# Rendering the Angular AppComponent as Standalone?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

Trying to "Switch" the Angular `AppComponent` to render as standalone after generating a new project using the CLI.  This attempt compiles fine, but the template does not render.

Here are the steps:

```
ng new project
cd project
```

Then change the `AppComponent` to look like this:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule, CommonModule],
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'b';
}
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent);
```

Also remove `AppComponent` from `app.module.ts` since it's now standalone.

Finally comment out this line in `main.ts` since we are bootstrapping the component.

```
/*
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
*/
```

If I now run `ng serve -o` the application compiles and boots, but the `app.component.html` template does not render.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you comment out bootstrapping the `AppModule`, don't forget to add bootstrapping the `AppComponent`. Your `main.ts` file should look like this:

```js
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideRouter, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

const routes: Routes = [];

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes)
  ]
});
```

You can find more details about bootstrapping a standalone component in the ["Bootstrapping an application using a standalone component"](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#bootstrapping-an-application-using-a-standalone-component) section of the standalone component documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `version` of `angular` that you are using supports `standalone components`.

You'll have to move `bootstrapApplication(AppComponent);` from `AppComponent` to `main.ts`, because it searches for this function in the `entry point` (`main` property) defined in the `angluar.json`.